# Automatic convention-based routing within a module in Zend Framework 2--possible?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc, zend-framework-modules, zend-framework-routing

I'm trying to understand all the configuration necessary to get my routing working in Zend Framework 2, and I can't help but wonder if I am making this more complicated than necessary.

I am working on a simple app that will follow a very simple convention:

/:module/:controller/:action

I've already created and wired up my module, "svc" (short for "service)".  I then created a second controller, the "ClientsController", and I can't get the routing to pass through my requests to, e.g., /svc/clients/list to ClientsController::listAction().

As I'm wading through hundreds of lines of configuration, in deeply nested arrays, I'm thinking--isn't there some way to just have a default mapping of my URLs to /:module/:controller/:action ?

Thanks for any assistance.  I'm going off of the [Zend Framework 2 Quick Start](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.quick-start.html), which walked me through creating a new module and then adding a controller to that module.  But when I tried to add second controller to that module, I am tripping over the routing.

**Update:** I didn't catch this the first time through, but apparently this is supposed to be a feature of the Zend Framework Skeleton app.  From the quick start guide:

> ZendSkeletonApplication ships with a “default route” that will likely
>   get you to this action. That route basically expects
>   “/{module}/{controller}/{action}”, which allows you to specify this:
>   “/zend-user/hello/world”

That's exactly what I want!  But I can't get it to work.

It lists an incomplete module.config.php, with a comment at the bottom about putting "other configuration" here.  I tried to figure out what that "other configuration" is, and wound up with this:

```
return array(
    'svc' => array(
        'type'    => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/svc',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller'    => 'svc\Controller\Index',
                'action'        => 'index',
            ),
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'svc\Controller\Clients' => 'svc\Controller\ClientsController',
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

JFYI, here is what my controller looks like.

```
namespace svc\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class ClientsController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function anotherAction(){

        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

My routes are not working.  I get "route not found" when I try to pull up any of my routes.

Comment: iirc you forgot to add the default `'__NAMESPACE__' => 'svc\Controller'` **edit**: but route not found is weird, what URL are you calling?

Comment: I added '__NAMESPACE__' => 'svc\Controller' and there's no change.  I've tried the following URLs: http://zf-sample.localhost/svc/clients/index, http://zf-sample.localhost/clients/index, http://zf-sample.localhost/svc/clients/another, http://zf-sample.localhost/clients/another.  All give "The requested URL could not be matched by routing."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It lists an incomplete module.config.php, with a comment at the bottom about putting "other configuration" here. I tried to figure out what that "other configuration" is, and wound up with this:

If your module.config.php really looks like that then it won't work, `routes` is an array of routes defined in the `router` key, your config contains no such spec, try replacing it with this

```
return array(
    // routes
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'svc' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/svc',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'svc\Controller\Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                 // add the default namespace for :controllers in this route
                                 '__NAMESPACE__' => 'svc\Controller',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),    
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'svc\Controller\Clients' => 'svc\Controller\ClientsController',
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: So I tried that and now I get: "clients(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: clients)".  This is at the URL http://zf-sample.localhost/svc/clients/another.  So apparently I need to somehow alias "clients" to my controller class... right?  But how do I do that?

Comment: Ok, so I changed this

 'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'svc\Controller\Clients' => 'svc\Controller\ClientsController',
        ),
    ),

to this:

 'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'clients' => 'svc\Controller\ClientsController',
        ),
    ),

And that seemed to do the trick.  Is that right?  Other than that change, I've got exactly what you posted.

Comment: no, as @Sam pointed out earlier, you'll need to add the `__NAMESPACE__` to your route config, see my edit.

Comment: Yes, that would be another way to do it. Doing it that way, if you ever have another module that also defines a `Clients` controller in the same manner, one of them will disappear when configs are merged. May not be an issue for your app, but something to keep in mind

Comment: Great, thanks!  It's working now.  Clarifying question: I see you put child_routes at $returnedArray['router']['routes']['svc']['child_routes'].  The Quick Start has child_routes at $returnedArray['svc']['childroutes'].  Why the difference?  It makes sense to my that child_routes would be a child of routes, so why would the quick start put it as a child of svc (and a sibling of routes)?  Here's the quick start link again: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.quick-start.html

Comment: You're looking for the docs from 2.0, current stable is 2.1.5, take a look at the skeleton app configuration from the 2.1* getting started guide -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html

Comment: I'm actually using 2.2.0 which I think is the latest stable based on the download links here: http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest. thanks for your help! I'm sure I'll be back with more questions...

Comment: Heh, it must be a week since I looked, my mistake, must have missed the announcement. If you're using 2.2 obviously you should be looking at those docs instead ;)