# ZF2 run the application without using the router

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am learning ZF2.

Is it possible to run the application without Router as in Zf1?
Do we need to define router for each controller?

Example:

In ZF1: `"admin/index/index"` shows as `"module/controller/action"`

IN ZF2: `"admin/index/index"` shows as `"router[/:controller][/:action]"`

please help me to clear my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Please tyr this

```
return array(
    // routes
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/album',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'album\Controller\Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                 // add the default namespace for :controllers in this route
                                 '__NAMESPACE__' => 'album\Controller',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),    
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'album\Controller\Test' => 'Album\Controller\TestController',
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

You need to add your controller name in invokables manually or invoke via Abstract Factories

```
'controllers' => array(
   'invokables' => array(
      'album\Controller\Test' => 'Album\Controller\TestController',
   ),
),
```

[Automatic Controller Invokables via Abstract Factories](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/zend-framework-2-automatic-controller-invokables-via-abstract-factories/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676825/automatic-convention-based-routing-within-a-module-in-zend-framework-2-possible)

Comment: I have two module. "user" and "admin". if i set this in "User" module then i have to define "router for "admin" module.

Comment: @Hasina, I have changed the code. Try this and let me know if it worked

Comment: Yes, you have to do this in each modules